# Equivalence of norm in a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normed-spaces

For the ring $$A=\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]=\{a+i\sqrt{3}b:a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ I had to show that the only invertible elements are $1$ and $-1$, using the norm $$N:\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]\quad \longrightarrow \quad \mathbb{N}\\ a+i\sqrt{3}b\mapsto a^2+3b^2$$

If $x=a+i\sqrt{3}b\in A$ is invertible then $\exists y\in A: xy=1_A$. With the proprety of the norm $N(x_1x_2)=N(x_1)N(x_2)$, we have 
$$1=N(1)=N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$$ 
which force $N(x)=a^2+3b^2=1$, and as $b^2\geq0, b\in \mathbb{Z}$, if $b\not =0$ then $3b^2\geq 3$. Therefore, $a^2=1$ and $b=0$.

However, I have difficulties understanding why this implies that $1$ and $-1$ are the **only** invertible elements of $A$.

Can't it be an other norm in which an element $x\in A\backslash\{-1,1\}$ is invertible ? I am not familiar with the notion of norm in Algebra (it is positive and multiplicative as far as I know), is it the same as in topology ? Is there some sort of a unique equivalence class of norm in this ring ?

Comment: You just showed if an element $x = a^2 + i√3b$ is invertible, then $a^2 = 1$ and $b = 0$, or in other words $a = \pm 1$ and $b = 0$, or in other words $x = \pm 1$. So any invertible element is $1$ or $-1$. What’s the problem?

Comment: @k.stm I was not sure why this implied that no other element is invertible. How can I prove there is no other norm in which an element different from $\pm 1$ would be invertible?

Comment: You do not need to this. Look carefully at the statement you have proven – there is no need to mention any norm or a condition like “invertible under such or such a norm”. You just and simply proved that **all invertible elements have to be $1$ or $-1$**. So **there are no other invertible elements**. The norm is only used for the proof of the statement, not for the statement itself.

Comment: Another way of looking at this: Take a candidate $x ∈ A \setminus\{1,-1\}$ and write $x = a + i√3b$. And say you found another clever norm which gives other, totally different *necesseray* conditions on $a$ and $b$. But, still if $x$ was invertible, using the *same norm as in your post* you still can conclude, as you did in your proof, $a^2 = 1$ and $b = 0$, so $x = \pm 1$. Other norms just don’t make your argument invalid. Notice that the conditions you find using norms by starting “suppose $x$ is invertible” are *necessary* conditions, not *sufficient* ones.

Comment: So technically, your proof shows that $1$ and $-1$ are the only *candidates* for invertible elements, which still leaves one to show that they *are* indeed invertible. But obviously, they are.

Comment: I understand now. I did not see it was a necessary condition, but now I do. Thank you very much!